# How to access RestFul Apis through Appium-TestNG framework in AWS-Device Farm?

Tags: appium, aws-device-farm

We have created our automation framework using Appium-TestNG in which we are accessing our backend servers through RestFul Apis externally. The backend server is also based on AWS and has whitelisted the device farm IPs. When we are executing the tests locally its working fine but when we execute it on AWS Device Farm, it is giving ‘Socket Exception’ when trying to access the backend servers via our apis.

Can anyone give us a solution of how to access external Rest APIS via Device Farm?

Comment: Are you making these calls from the tests or is the request coming from the device? Also could you provide a stacktrace of the socket exception?

Comment: We are making this calls from the tests. Following is the stacktrace: "test" - @BeforeMethod Android.Regression.EditPersonalInformation.setup()
wawa_api.commons.ApiException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
 at wawa_api.commons.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:840)
 at wawa_api.mobagteway.AuthenticationControllerV4Api.getClientCredentialsUsingPOST1WithHttpInfo(AuthenticationControllerV4Api.java:134)
 at wawa_api.mobagteway.AuthenticationControllerV4Api.getClientCredentialsUsingPOST1(AuthenticationControllerV4Api.java:118)

Answer (score 1):

The IP range that's in the [FAQ of Device Farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/faq/) point to the devices but not the device host. The device host could have a wide range of IPs but there are two ways(that I've found so far) to get around this issue in theory:

1. Use the private offering from Device Farm.

If you have access to the private offering for Device Farm, you're able to use the [VPC integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/amazon-vpc-endpoints.html) with both the devices and the device host. So there shouldn't be any white-listing needed using this method.

2. Use API Gateway's [private VPC integration](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-api-gateway-supports-endpoint-integrations-with-private-vpcs/) and call this API from the tests

When using the public offering([metered](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/pricing/#payAsYouGo) and [unmetered](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/03/pay-a-flat-monthly-fee-for-unlimited-testing-of-your-android-and-ios-apps-with-aws-device-farm-device-slots/) options) we should be able to take advantage of API Gateway's VPC integration. Using an private NLB in the same VPC as the REST API we can create a VPC link. The ending architecture I believe should look like this:

[image: Device host to REST API]

Then we can secure the API using an [API key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-restapi.html) or [custom authorizers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html). So then we can call this API which links to the private REST API from the device host.

Note: This might not be the best workaround depending on the use-case as then the device host will have access to the API key.

Additionally(I know you didn't ask this but wanted to link to it anyway), the easiest way I've found so far to develop REST API calls is to use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to make a successful call to the REST API. Then use the [code snippet](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets) feature to make the same calls in the support languages from postman.

Hope that helps

-James

Comment: Thanks James..I will look into it and get back to you.

Comment: Hi James,

Can you please elaborate more on below option:

“Additionally(I know you didn't ask this but wanted to link to it anyway), the easiest way I've found so far to develop REST API calls is to use Postman to make a successful call to the REST API. Then use the code snippet feature to make the same calls in the support languages from postman.”

Thanks
Gautam

Comment: I just mean that you can use that feature to write code for the request to the API. Lots of people don't know about it so I wanted to share